# Regex: Match all occurrences between specified strings

Tags: regex

I'm dealing with a bunch of text files that refer to image filenames. These filenames were sanitized (made lowercase and whitespace replaced with hyphens) - but the text referring to them was not.

I need to transform strings like this:

```
(image: uploaded IMAGE.jpg caption: this is my caption)
(image: uploaded IMAGE copy.jpeg caption: this is my caption)
(image: IMG_6087.png caption: this is my caption)
(image: IMG_6087 copy.gif)
(image: IMG_9999_copy.jpg)
(image: somehow, a comma.jpg)
(image: other ridic'ulous characters!.jpg)
```

to:

```
(image: uploaded-image.jpg caption: this is my caption)
(image: uploaded-image-copy.jpeg caption: this is my caption)
(image: img_6087.png caption: this is my caption)
(image: img_6087-copy.gif)
(image: img_9999_copy.jpg)
(image: somehow-a-comma.jpg)
(image: other-ridiculous-characters.jpg)
```

These strings are parts of larger blocks of text, but are all on their own lines, like so:

```
This is not a short guide to write about art. Go in, out of the window, inside New York’s stars qualities, dreams and schemes. People are gathered together, brewing coffee — you have seen their faces? The artists in Manhattan.

(image: manhattan photo.jpg)

Drive till sunset and say goodbye to your body, because this is not a photograph. I saw sixteen americans, raised by wolves, probably lost in paradise city. I found your head — Do you still want it?
```

I'm using Sublime text and was planning on doing multiple Replace Alls:

1. strip whitespace
2. strip characters that are not alphanumeric or _ or -
3. make lowercase

But I can't manage to capture all instances of something between the two delimiters.

`(?<=^\(image: )[what do I do here??](?=\.jpe?g|png|gif)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use non-greedy match-all `.*?`

so `^\(image: (.*?\.(:?jpe?g|png|gif))` to capture the filename including extension

Comment: This captures the entire filename, so I'm able to make it lowercase using search: `(?<=^\(image: )(.*?)(?=\.jpe?g|png|gif)` replace: `\L$1` - so that solves step #3 - but how to find and replace all spaces with hyphens?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the filenames with:

```
(?<=image:\s)([^.]++)(?=\.jpe?g|\.png|\.gif)
```

After that, the transformations depend on the language that you're working in. Add file extensions as you need them. Right now you support `jpg`, `jpeg`, `png`, and `gif`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working way to do it in PHP

```
<?php
$string =
"This is not a short guide to write about art. Go in, out of the window, inside New York’s stars qualities, dreams and schemes. People are gathered together, brewing coffee — you have seen their faces? The artists in Manhattan.

(image: uploaded IMAGE.jpg caption: this is my caption)
This is not a short guide to write about art. Go in, out of the window, inside New York’s stars qualities, dreams and schemes. People are gathered together, brewing coffee — you have seen their faces? The artists in Manhattan.

(image: uploaded IMAGE copy.jpeg caption: this is my caption)
(image: IMG_6087.png caption: this is my caption)
(image: IMG_6087 copy.gif) blah blah
(image: IMG_9999_copy.jpg)
(image: somehow, a comma.jpg)
(image: other ridic'ulous characters!.jpg)";

echo preg_replace_callback('~(?<=\(image: )(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)~', function($matches)
{
    return preg_replace('~\W~', '-', stripslashes(strtolower($matches[1]))) . ".$matches[2]";
}, $string);

?>
```

[EDIT] add regex explanation:

- `(?<=image: )`: is a positive lookbehind - so checking the presence of 'image: ' but not capturing.
- `(.*?)`: captures everything before the image extension in a greedy way - so match as few text as possible.
- `\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)`: will match `.` literally + one of the given extensions - and capturing the extension to reuse.
- `~`: is the delimiter, this choice just because it is very seldom used in strings and won't need to `\` the `/`
- `\W`: is the opposite of `\w` and it will match any non-alphanumeric character.

Will output (in view source):

```
This is not a short guide to write about art. Go in, out of the window, inside New York’s stars qualities, dreams and schemes. People are gathered together, brewing coffee — you have seen their faces? The artists in Manhattan.

(image: uploaded-image.jpg caption: this is my caption)
This is not a short guide to write about art. Go in, out of the window, inside New York’s stars qualities, dreams and schemes. People are gathered together, brewing coffee — you have seen their faces? The artists in Manhattan.

(image: uploaded-image-copy.jpeg caption: this is my caption)
(image: img_6087.png caption: this is my caption)
(image: img_6087-copy.gif) blah blah
(image: img_9999_copy.jpg)
(image: somehow--a-comma.jpg)
(image: other-ridic-ulous-characters-.jpg)
```

You can then fine-tune in the callback what character you want to transform into what, with str_replace() for instance.

hope it helps! ;)